# Blank page after login on WildFly 10

Tags: jsf, wildfly, j-security-check, wildfly-10

I've deployed an application on Wildfly 10, that is working correctly on GlassFish, but I'm getting a blank page `/<context_path>/j_security_check` when I try to login.
I've looked some posts suggesting to include cache control request headers, but it didn't resolve the problem.
The logs do not show any kind of error or relevant information and I really don't know what to try next.
Has anyone experienced any similar issue?

**EDIT 1**
The authentication is working correctly. If, afterwards, I try to access a protected resource, I'm able to do so. It's just the redirect after the login that is not being triggered.

**EDIT 2**
The Request/Response dump:

```
----------------------------REQUEST---------------------------
               URI=/ecc
characterEncoding=null
     contentLength=-1
       contentType=null
            cookie=EPMSID=sfTmDLw92HjAhwfY7HUei5fzlUbwKjxUg3EhyTMk.d014349
            header=Accept=text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
            header=Connection=Keep-Alive
            header=Accept-Language=pt-PT
            header=Accept-Encoding=gzip, deflate
            header=Cookie=EPMSID=sfTmDLw92HjAhwfY7HUei5fzlUbwKjxUg3EhyTMk.d014349
            header=User-Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)
            header=Host=localhost:8443
            locale=[pt_PT]
            method=GET
          protocol=HTTP/1.1
       queryString=
        remoteAddr=/127.0.0.1:62990
        remoteHost=sibshare
            scheme=https
              host=localhost:8443
        serverPort=8443
--------------------------RESPONSE--------------------------
     contentLength=0
       contentType=null
            header=Connection=keep-alive
            header=X-Powered-By=Undertow/1
            header=Server=WildFly/10
            header=Location=https://localhost:8443/ecc/
            header=Content-Length=0
            header=Date=Mon, 09 May 2016 08:18:33 GMT
            status=302
==============================================================
2016-05-09 09:18:33,890 INFO  [stdout] (default task-5) [DEBUG] ecc_src - NoCacheFilter:Initializing filter
2016-05-09 09:18:33,902 INFO  [io.undertow.request.dump] (default task-5)
----------------------------REQUEST---------------------------
               URI=/ecc/
characterEncoding=null
     contentLength=-1
       contentType=null
            cookie=EPMSID=sfTmDLw92HjAhwfY7HUei5fzlUbwKjxUg3EhyTMk.d014349
            header=Accept=text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
            header=Connection=Keep-Alive
            header=Accept-Language=pt-PT
            header=Accept-Encoding=gzip, deflate
            header=Cookie=EPMSID=sfTmDLw92HjAhwfY7HUei5fzlUbwKjxUg3EhyTMk.d014349
            header=User-Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)
            header=Host=localhost:8443
            locale=[pt_PT]
            method=GET
          protocol=HTTP/1.1
       queryString=
        remoteAddr=/127.0.0.1:62989
        remoteHost=sibshare
            scheme=https
              host=localhost:8443
        serverPort=8443
--------------------------RESPONSE--------------------------
     contentLength=239
       contentType=text/html
            header=Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
            header=Cache-Control=no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
            header=X-Powered-By=Undertow/1
            header=Server=WildFly/10
            header=Pragma=no-cache
            header=Accept-Ranges=bytes
            header=Date=Mon, 09 May 2016 08:18:33 GMT
            header=Connection=keep-alive
            header=ETag=W/"239-1462554016000"
            header=Last-Modified=Fri, 06 May 2016 17:00:16 GMT
            header=Content-Type=text/html
            header=Content-Length=239
            status=200
==============================================================
2016-05-09 09:18:34,112 INFO  [io.undertow.request.dump] (default task-6)
----------------------------REQUEST---------------------------
               URI=/ecc/secure/home.jsf
characterEncoding=null
     contentLength=-1
       contentType=null
            cookie=EPMSID=sfTmDLw92HjAhwfY7HUei5fzlUbwKjxUg3EhyTMk.d014349
            header=Accept=text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
            header=Connection=Keep-Alive
            header=Accept-Language=pt-PT
            header=Accept-Encoding=gzip, deflate
            header=Cookie=EPMSID=sfTmDLw92HjAhwfY7HUei5fzlUbwKjxUg3EhyTMk.d014349
            header=User-Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)
            header=Host=localhost:8443
            locale=[pt_PT]
            method=GET
          protocol=HTTP/1.1
       queryString=
        remoteAddr=sibshare/127.0.0.1:62990
        remoteHost=sibshare
            scheme=https
              host=localhost:8443
        serverPort=8443
--------------------------RESPONSE--------------------------
     contentLength=2897
       contentType=text/html;charset=UTF-8
            cookie=EPMSID=KcblRlqogTv4hCuVtjeL27onM3Nbp04k--DDZfnt.d014349; domain=null; path=/ecc
            header=Expires=0
            header=Expires=0
            header=Cache-Control=no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
            header=Cache-Control=no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
            header=X-Powered-By=Undertow/1
            header=Set-Cookie=EPMSID=KcblRlqogTv4hCuVtjeL27onM3Nbp04k--DDZfnt.d014349; path=/ecc; secure; HttpOnly
            header=Server=WildFly/10
            header=Pragma=no-cache
            header=Pragma=no-cache
            header=Date=Mon, 09 May 2016 08:18:34 GMT
            header=Connection=keep-alive
            header=Content-Type=text/html;charset=UTF-8
            header=Content-Length=2897
            status=200
==============================================================
2016-05-09 09:18:44,841 INFO  [io.undertow.request.dump] (default task-13)
----------------------------REQUEST---------------------------
               URI=/ecc/j_security_check
characterEncoding=null
     contentLength=68
       contentType=[application/x-www-form-urlencoded]
            cookie=EPMSID=KcblRlqogTv4hCuVtjeL27onM3Nbp04k--DDZfnt.d014349
            header=Accept=text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
            header=Accept-Language=pt-PT
            header=Cache-Control=no-cache
            header=Accept-Encoding=gzip, deflate
            header=User-Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)
            header=Connection=Keep-Alive
            header=Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded
            header=Content-Length=68
            header=Cookie=EPMSID=KcblRlqogTv4hCuVtjeL27onM3Nbp04k--DDZfnt.d014349
            header=Referer=https://localhost:8443/ecc/secure/home.jsf
            header=Host=localhost:8443
            locale=[pt_PT]
           method=POST
          protocol=HTTP/1.1
       queryString=
        remoteAddr=sibshare/127.0.0.1:62993
        remoteHost=sibshare
            scheme=https
              host=localhost:8443
        serverPort=8443
--------------------------RESPONSE--------------------------
     contentLength=0
       contentType=null
            cookie=EPMSID=JtIoopj1u-p_Ko95XwYi45HqkdzNBVRxSklVFQEL.d014349; domain=null; path=/ecc
            header=Expires=0
            header=Cache-Control=no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
            header=X-Powered-By=Undertow/1
            header=Set-Cookie=EPMSID=JtIoopj1u-p_Ko95XwYi45HqkdzNBVRxSklVFQEL.d014349; path=/ecc; secure; HttpOnly
            header=Server=WildFly/10
            header=Pragma=no-cache
            header=Date=Mon, 09 May 2016 08:18:44 GMT
            header=Connection=keep-alive
            header=Content-Length=0
            status=200
==============================================================
```

Comment: Are there clues in the browser log / network traffic ?

Comment: No, nothing at all. I tried to dump the request but it seems normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured out what is wrong.
In my login page I've the following listener configured for invalidating the active session:

```
<f:metadata>
<f:event  type="preRenderView" listener="#{manager.invalidateActiveSession}" />
</f:metadata>
```

This listener simply invalidates the session (if it exists):

```
HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false);

if (session != null ) {
    synchronized( session ) {
        session.invalidate();
    }
}
```

And this is what is causing the strange behavior. This same code works fine on GlassFish.
I've changed the code to, additionally, verify if the Principal is also not null.